# Unable to connect Node-Red running locally with Watson IoT platform on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, api-key, watson-iot

I am unable to connect to the Watson IoT platform from a Node Red installed locally on my system.

I have installed the ibmiot node. In connection details, I selected Authentication as "API Key". In the API Key settings, for API Key, I specified the key that I generated from the Watson Iot platform; in API Token, the token that got generated with the API Key; in the server field, I specified org_id.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com.
I have also configured the Device Type and Device ID. However, the node isn't connecting to the Watson IoT platform.

What could be the issue? I think it is probably due to the API Key. I am not sure what is the right way of doing this. Help is appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of how the API Key and Token was generated.
[image]

This is how I configured the node:
[image]

This is the API Key configuration:
[image]

Comment: do you receive any error messages when deploying or after deploying the node?

Comment: @idan Yes, it says ECONNRESET on the debug console. I think this is probably because it is unable to contact the server. I do not know what is the correct server name. I used the one specified in the hint and put my org_id. This never happened earlier when I used node red with Raspberry pi, it did not even ask for server name. Something has changed.

Comment: This is the error that I see: [error] [ibmiot in:IBM IoT] Error: read ECONNRESET

Answer (score 1):

I think I have got the issue. Watson IoT uses MQTT to communicate. It must have the firewall configuration set correctly. Traffic on Port 1883 should be allowed. Here is a link to the documentation: [Connecting to applications](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#connect_devices_apps_gw)
I will not be able to do this since I behind the corporate network. But hope it helps someone trying to connect using locally installed Node-Red. :)

Answer (score 0):

ports 1883 (unsecured connections), 8883 and 443 (secured connections) are use with IBM WIoTP and needs to be opened on firewall

Comment: right, mentioned that in my answer above. Do have any idea how to use api keys and auth tokens for using the Watson IoT APIs? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/IoT/reference?topic=iot-platform-api_overview#api_overview. I am trying to hit one Information Management API from Postman and unable to get a response. I keep getting 403.

Comment: the apikey and token that you have on above should be enough to use with the api. What service do you want to call? Not sure, but I think it would be good to address this on a separate question on stackoverflow

Comment: It was for event caching. Got it, I had to enable event caching from the UI. Isn't there any other way to get simulated events from Watson IoT except for event cache?